# GROUP BY rewrite to subqueries with easily interchangeable AND OR conditions

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, query-performance

Tables:

```
content        tag_map       extrainfo
|id|title|    |id|tagid|    |id|lat|lng|
|--|-----|    |--|-----|    |--|---|---|
|1 |Lorem|    |1 |8    |    |3 |0,4|0,1|
|2 |Ipsum|    |2 |9    |    |2 |1,1|1,2|
|3 |Dolor|    |1 |9    |
              |1 |7    |
```

id is unique index

```
SELECT * FROM content, tag_map, extrainfo
WHERE
tag_map.id = content.id
AND
extrainfo.id = content.id

#AND OR conditions here
#conditions can be very different but I would like
#to use the same query structure
#just change conditions here as necessary

GROUP BY content.id
```

this query works - but slow.
I found the most alternatives involve subqueries, but I can`t figure out a way to use subqueries and still be able to **freely change AND OR** conditions that **involve columns from ALL tables**.

Other non-subquery methods are welcome too.

Comment: Please show us the output from the two variations.

Comment: OR can be bad for performance in some cases. Ad-hoc queries are even worse. Have indexes on fields which might show in there and give some reasonable selectivity. ORs can be turned to UNION (ALL) - you build the query with all ANDs and then clone it once for each OR and either run them separately or UNION them in one query. The problem is that it does not make sense for every column, only some of them. So again ad-hoc structure may be a problem (you might keep a list of columns for which it has positive effect, but it changes with addition of other conditions too..)

Comment: Why is the `GROUP BY` used? Having `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY some_column` will give you unpredictable and non-sensible results.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First clean the join syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM content as c
inner join tag_map as t on c.id=t.id 
inner join extrainfo as e on c.id=e.id
WHERE
#AND OR conditions here
#conditions can be very different but I would like
#to use the same query structure
#just change conditions here as necessary
GROUP BY c.id
```

Now substitute your and/or clauses in place of the rem'd out lines above. Then look into indexing those columns (indexes should cover all the fields in the conditions).

These simple steps will speed up significantly. If you need further speed ups, please post before and after speedup results along with complete details of existing indexes.

Comment: @EmacsUser you can hardly create covering indexes for "user generated" queries (thats what I understand from that placeholder for conditions in the question). And I want to second what Paul wrote, the first sentence is just wrong.

Comment: @jkavalik I'm afraid I don't follow your first part about indexes. I edited for the second part.

Comment: I think @jkavalik's point (which I'd agree with) is that the user generated queries could have all sorts of conditions, referencing various columns in various combinations. Adding all possible covering indices would probably be feasible, technically, but hardly sensible.

Comment: That's the trade-off, speed versus convenience. Any good DBA would monitor for such trade-offs and pick what's sensible. Why is giving those options to look into not sensible? Because technically there is no reason why those fields cannot be indexed to begin with? It goes to the main premise of the question: slow query.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestions. Indexes really improved performance. To anyone reading with similar problem: TAKE THE TIME TO DO INDEXES the results WILL SURPRISE YOU. It is also simple if your needs are not very specific - in phpMyAdmin just click 'index' in structure tab

Comment: @ArmandP well, my take from what EmacsUser wrote was to properly analyze your queries and pick the best indexes possible for the greatest range of queries. Having some indexes at least should be by default..

Comment: @ArmandP: In case you are new to the concept of indices – yes, they can be a great help, performance-wise, when reading data. Too many of them, however, can also *negatively* affect performance when *modifying* data (inserting, updating, deleting). Just so you better understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thank's @AndriyM . I am new to  indices. In this project slow data insert is not an issue but thank you for the heads up. In my next project I'll need fast insert and fast select, but that is a topic for another question.